# Nivo Slider not printing - How do i get my nivo slider images printed out?

Tags: jquery, css, printing, slider, nivo-slider

I can't print the nivo slider (default-theme):
http://nivo.dev7studios.com/theme-demos/

I don't know why and I'm trying to get a solution for a few days now.

I tried stuff like

```
#slider {
  visibility: visible;
  width:      950px;
  height:     350px;
  overflow:   visible;
  display:    block;
  position:   relative; 
  z-index:    50;
}
```

in a print.css. Nothing works

I would be very happy if someone could have a look at it.

Comment: there's is no `link` with `media=print` in that page

Comment: IMHO, web pages are for viewing on a screen.  If you want something to print out nicely, create a pamphlet.  If you want something available online that looks like a pamphlet, create a PDF for downloading/printing.  Getting a complex web page to print consistently across all browsers **and** look like what's on the screen is a real pain and nearly impossible when you have dynamic content like an image slider.

Answer (score 0):

for printing images:

see the Demo http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/JDvHm/

OR read full article: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/printpart.html